# How does the precedence is working with comparison operators in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, comparison-operators, operator-precedence

I'm using **PHP 7.2.0**

I wrote following code :

```
<?php
echo 1 <= 5 == 1;
?>
```

and I got following output in my web browser :

```
1
```

I expected none(false) or 0 to be the output but surprisingly I got `1` as an output.

I'm not able to understand how does the precedence get worked out here.

Can someone please explain me how the precedence got worked in this code in a step-by-step manner?

Thank You.

Comment: Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 <= 5` is `true`,
`true == 1` is `true`,
`echo true` outputs `1`.

The precedence is:

```
echo (1 <= 5) == 1;
```